# Application Bar items in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

in my windows phone app, i have an application bar menu item named item_1 and radiobutton button_1 , i have put the IsEnabled property of the item_1 as false; and so when i check the button_1 the IsEnabled property of  item_1 should be made true; for that i have written the following code in c#

```
 public void button_1_checked(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    this.item_1.IsEnabled=true;
    -----rest of the code----
 }
```

but this is giving a NullReferenceException , what should i do to make the item_1 enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the ApplicationBar does not get properly bound via the Name property. You need to access it via code:

```
var button1 = (ApplicationBarIconButton) ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
button1.IsEnabled = true;
```

This link might be helpful for you: [How to: Create an Application Bar in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431786%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)